# Find the interval in which $x^n(1-x^2)$ converges point wise and find its limit function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the interval in which the sequence $x^n(1-x^2)$ converges point wise and find its limit function.

My attempt so far:

I drew a picture of the function

[image]

and it seems that I can focus on the interval $[-1,1]$. However, I am not sure how to do this otherwise that by looking at the picture. Is there a way I can figure out the interval in another way?

Comment: Focusing on the interval $[-1, 1]$ is a good start. Now answer these questions: If $x\in[-1, 1]$, does $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n(1-x^2)$ converge? If so, what is the limit? What if $x\notin[-1, 1]$? If it converges, what is the limit?

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is that $x^n$ get's very small for values $|x|<1$. Note that for $x\in (-1,1)$, 
$$
|f_n(x)|=|x|^n(1-x^2)\leq |x|^n\to 0
$$
And $f_n(\pm 1)=0$.

For $|x|>1$, $x^n$ explodes, or oscillates with greater and greater heights, depending on the sign of $x$. This won't go well with convergence.

Indeed, suppose you had a pointwise limit, then by the reverse triangle ineq. 
$$
|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq |f_n(x)|-|f(x)|=|x|^n|1-x^2|-|f(x)|
$$
and so has no hope of going to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Pointwise convergence is related with simple limits. If $x = \pm 1$ the $f_{n}(x) \equiv 0$ for all $n$. If $x \in (-1,1)$ the the limit $x^{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}(1-x^{2})$ converges pointwise to $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: My bad, I meant $x \in (-1,1)$. I will edit it! Thanks!